# How to compile console application to 3.5 version

Tags: .net

I have a .net Console application in 1.0 version. I have converted that application into 2010. Now need to compile the application in .Net 3.5. Is there any way where I can set the compile version for console application. However, when I compile the Class Library there is a Target Framework option in the property of the project. But in the Console application I do not see any option.

Answer (score 1):

Open Project Properties Page, and change Target Framework to your desire

[image]

Comment: This option is not available on Console Application.

Comment: There always have Target framework for .net project. You should check again